# How to fix ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fpdf' when the module and python are in the same location

Tags: python, web-scraping

I used the codes below to download a pdf online:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

req = Request('https://www.williams.edu/institutional-research/files/2021/09/2020-2021_CDS_Williams_College_tuit-2.pdf', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
response = urlopen(req)
#webpage
save_path = 'C:/Users/WM' 
file_name = '2020-2021'
complete_name = os.path.join(save_path, file_name)
file = open(complete_name, 'wb')
file.write(response.read())
file.close()
print("Completed")
```

The result is I got two files in the designated folder: one is File and the other is PDF. When I opened the PDF, it says Adobe Acrobat Reader could not open it because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged. If I opened the File and choose to open with Adobe Acrobat Reader, I was able to successfully open it. So, I tried to convert the File type to PDF type.
Here is what I ran:

```
from fpdf import FPDF
   
# save FPDF() class into 
# a variable pdf
pdf = FPDF()   
   
# Add a page
pdf.add_page()
   
# set style and size of font 
# that you want in the pdf
pdf.set_font("Arial", size = 15)
# open the text file in read mode
f = open("2020-2021.File", "r")
  
# insert the texts in pdf
for x in f:
    pdf.cell(200, 10, txt = x, ln = 1, align = 'C')

#save the pdf with name .pdf
pdf.output("2020-2021.pdf")
```

However, I got an error saying that ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fpdf'. I checked the location where the fpdf is saved, it was saved in the C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages. The Python 3.9 is saved in the C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39. May I know how to fix the problem? Thank you!

Comment: Did you use pip to install the package? If so, what command did you run?

Comment: Hi, I used pip install fpdf. My pip version is 22.0.4. I checked online the version is compatible with Python 3.9 that is the version installed.

Comment: In the code the statement `save_path = 'C:/Users/WM' makes it appear the user name is WM. So, the path `C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages` does not seem right. Seems like it should be `C:\Users\WM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages`. Open a command prompt and enter the command `where python`. See if this gives clues on the issue. Not sure how the python program is being launched. `where python` will list if more than one python.exe is in the path.

Comment: I solved the problem by adding .pdf to the file name, so I don't have to download the fpdf module and convert the file to pdf.